# How to make connection between two laptops at different location

Tags: java

I have developed a chat application in java in which i want to connect with different peoples at different places. So how it can be done?
As i have connected two laptops through adhoc network(wireless) in same room but now want to connect with friend where both are at different location.

Comment: They need to find each other, punch through firewalls, etc. That's a very **broad** topic. Just for finding each other, you'd need a server to coordinate that.

Comment: Please refined the subject to one specific topic/problem. This can't be answer for the moment. See [ask]

Comment: Magic key is **WebSocket**

Comment: From networking point of view what you want to do is virtually impossible. You can not establish a p2p connection without a third-party server, and even then it is often not possible and requires certain adjustments on a firewall or router.

Comment: @Dariusz: You can connect two instances of the same program without a third one (server) - just have both open a ServerSocket (Only one will be needed.), tell the other person the IP, the person's instance uses a Socket to attempt to connect to that IP - done.

Comment: @DreamspacePresident - 1) you need ip:port not just ip, 2) you're assuming they're in the same network, which is a very strong assumption. Any NAT or firewall in between will make your way of establishing the connection not work.

Comment: You're right about 2), but 1) could be a pre-defined standard port that this application always uses but that *could* be changed if need be. The port would only have to be given in that case.